# What will the RightSignature API send to my callback URL when a signer signs a document

Tags: iframe, electronic-signature

When I send a one-off document to RightSignature via their API, I'm specifying a callback location in the XML document as specified in RightSignature's schema definition.  I then get a signer-link value back from their API for the document.  I display the HTML response from the signer-link URL in an iFrame on our website.  When our user signs the document in this iFrame, which is rendering the responses from their website, I want their website to post to our callback location.

Can I do this with the RightSignature API and does it make sense?

So far, I'm only getting content in the iFrame that indicates that the signing was successful.  The callback location does not seem to be getting called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer with some help from the API team at RightSignature.  I was using callback_location but what I really wanted is redirect_location.  Their online documentation was difficult to follow and did not clearly point out the difference.
I got this working after a lot of trial and error.

Comment: I also downloaded 'Right Signature API files (ZIP)' from their site. But, where to start i am not getting. If you have any document related to work structure or data flow, please give me a link. I would like to see. One more question, i included the embedded link of one document (means `<iframe>...</iframe>`), how to send values of that `<iframe>` to XML. I am not getting anywhere to start. Please guide me. *Taa-Urm Aapki Ijjat Karunga.*

Comment: They sent us a sample application after someone on our team asked for one.  I spent days working through what their sample application was doing.  I spent additional days working through how to get it to do what we needed.  I emailed questions to their api-support address, and usually got a response in a day or two.  The responses were sometimes helpful.

Comment: @HungryDB, I provided as much detail as I thought I should.  My statement that "I got this working after a lot of trial and error" is extra information that could help someone who thinks that the RightSignature API is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved just now. Basically, i was doing two things wrong first you have to go in RightSignature Account and set it there the CallBack url

Account > Settings > Advanced Settings

But the thing which RS is unable to mention to us that this url can not be of localhost, but it should be of https i mean like Live URL of your site like

https://stagingmysite.azurewebsites.net/User/CallBackFunction

And then in your CallBack just write these two lines and you will receive complete XML which would have the GUID and document status as well.

```
byte[] data = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes); 
string callBackXML = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your solution.  Perhaps that would have been an alternate solution to our problem as well.